# rsync error: Bad file number (9)

Tags: rsync, drupal

I looked everywhere to find a solution...I keep on getting this error:

```
rsync: change_dir "/cygdrive/C/Users/mloch/Desktop/sites/drupalsite1/" failed: Bad file number (9)
rsync: mkdir "/cygdrive/C/Users/mloch/Desktop/sites/drupalsite2" failed: Bad file number (9)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /usr/src/rsync/rsync-3.0.8/main.c(587) [Receiver=3.0.8]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /usr/src/rsync/rsync-3.0.8/io.c(601) [sender=3.0.8]
Could not rsync from /cygdrive/C/...drupalsite1// to "/cygdrive/C/...drupalsite2//"
```

Some forums say it might be the that rsync has no access to tmp folder.

Comment: Maybe dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892125/cygwin-rsync-protocol-error)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks mloch, This is the only solution to this problem I have found after hours and hours of trying everything else...

> To get rsync and sql-sync to work on remote server using Windows (w/Aquia) it is necessary to make changes to 2 files filesystem.inc and SqlBase.php.
>
> First delete **cygdrive/** from **$path = preg_replace('/cygdrive/(\w):/', '/${1}', >str_replace('\', '/', $path));** in line 61 of filesystem.inc and change **drush_shell_exec('gzip -d %s', $input_file)**
>
> instead of
>
> **drush_shell_exec('gunzip %s', $input_file)** in line 144 of SqlBase.php
>
> Happy Syncing!

Although in my case all I needed to do is remove the **cygdrive/** in filesystem.inc...

It seemed to work fine without changing 'gzip' to 'gunzip'.

Now there's gotta be a better solution to this problem than modifying drush's code, but for now it solves the issue with rsync / sql-sync.

For clarification for others, these files are (most likely) found in:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\includes
- C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\drush\vendor\drush\drush\lib\Drush\Sql

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Did your sql-sync work though without the gunzip change?

Comment: I haven't had any issues with sql-sync (or rsync) with leaving the gzip/gunzip as-is.

Which is kind of weird because according to the original code, it looks as if its supposed to be gunzip

`if (drush_shell_exec('gzip -d %s', $input_file)) {
        $input_file = trim($input_file, '.gz');
      }
      else {
        return drush_set_error(dt('Failed to decompress input file.'));
      }`

... Whatever... if this part ain't broke, I'm not gonna change it...

Comment: Folowing the above I end-up with a code 0 error:


ssh -i privatekey.ppk user@Site.dd "env COLUMNS=177 drush  --backend=2 --verbose --strict=0 --root=/home/User/Site.dd          [notice]
--uri=http://Site.dd  sql-query   --file=/tmp/DB_20170214_163301.sql.gz --file-delete 2>&1" 2>&1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.27
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
[error]
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
, code: 0)
Command dispatch complete                                                                                                                                                [notice]

Answer (score -2):

To get rsync and sql-sync to work on remote server using Windows (w/Aquia) it is necessary to make changes to 2 files filesystem.inc and SqlBase.php.

First delete **cygdrive/** from  **$path = preg_replace('/cygdrive/(\w):/', '/${1}', str_replace('\', '/', $path));** in line 61 of filesystem.inc and change **drush_shell_exec('gzip -d %s', $input_file)**

instead of

**drush_shell_exec('gunzip %s', $input_file)** in line 144 of SqlBase.php

Happy Syncing!

Comment: "I'll finish later" does not make an answer.

Comment: Thanks Dave, nice to know someone else looks at this question... I need to get back on my laptop to finish the exact answer that solved the problem for me haven't had time yet, but it's better then nothing to set people in the right direction. The first part I figured out myself and the second took a long time of searching (almost by accident)... If you need it desperately I can get it up quicker

Comment: Actually, thanks, I might delete the post and give it a new title since this is a smaller problem of a bigger one